# How to predict the emplyoee salary in 2020 using the previous data using Regression algorithm using C#?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

How to predict the salary of employee 2020 using regression algorithm.

b = (n * Sum(xy) - Sum(x)Sum(y)) / (n * Sum(x^2) - Sum(x)^2).

//Formula  Sum represents Summation of

a = (Sum(y)/n)-b(Sum(x)/n)

regression formula : (y = a + bx)

Please help me to find the salary in 2020 using algorithms.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What bit in particular are you having difficulty with? What have you tried? Please [edit] your question to include this information. Thanks!

Comment: @bertieb I have used the regression algorithm to predict the salary of an employee in 2020.

Comment: @bertieb please verify this link for your prediction of salary, instead of using formula you can use ML.Net
https://www.wintellect.com/machine-learning-c-introduction-ml-net/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
using System;
public class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Employee Salary Prediction for 2020 using Regression Algorithm");
  int[,] xyInputs= new int[,]{{2002,1000},{2003,2000},{2004,3000},{2005,4000},{2006,5000},{2007,6000},{2008,7000}
         ,{2009,8000},{2010,9000},{2011,10000},{2012,11000},{2013,12000},{2015,13000},{2016,14000}
         ,{2017,15000}};
            //consider those values like x and y for the regression formula (y = a + bx;)
  int xValueyValue=0; 
  int xValue=0;
  int yValue=0;
  int xSquareValue=0;
  int lastSalary=0;
   
  for (int i=0;i<xyInputs.Length/2;i++)
  {
   int temp=0;
   for (int j=0;j < xyInputs.Length/2;j++)
      {    
    try{
     
     if(j==0){
       temp =xyInputs[i,j];
           xValue = xValue + temp;
       xSquareValue = xSquareValue + xValue * xValue ;
       }
     if(j==1){
       xValueyValue = xValueyValue + (temp * xyInputs[i,j]);
       yValue = yValue + xyInputs[i,j];
       temp=0;
             }
     if(i == ((xyInputs.Length/2)-1)){
          lastSalary=(xyInputs[i,j]);
           }
       }catch(Exception ex){
     
       }
    
   }
  }
  //Formula  Sum represents Sumation of  b = (n * Sum(xy) - Sum(x)Sum(y)) / (n * Sum(x^2) - Sum(x)^2). 
     int b =(xyInputs.Length * ((xValueyValue) - (xValue * yValue)))/((xyInputs.Length * xSquareValue)- (xValue * xValue));
  //Formula  Sum represents Sumation of a = (Sum(y)/n)-b(Sum(x)/n)
  int a = (yValue  - (b * xValue))/xyInputs.Length;
  Console.WriteLine("Regression y Value for x = 2020 is :" +(lastSalary + (a + (b * 2020))));
    
 }
}
```